# How can I disable checkboxes and radio buttons from separate components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Running into this ReactJS (with Redux) issue:

[image]

If premium white isn’t selected, gloss finish should be disabled. The radio button (premium) and checkbox (gloss) have separate methods in separate components – looks like they are both using state to send data.

Here’s the checkbox

```
  buildCheckbox(item) {
    return (
      <Checkbox
        key={item.key}
        label={item.display}
        name={item.key}
        checked={this.props.order[item.key] || false}
        onChange={checked => this.handleCheck(checked, item.key)}
        disabled={item.disabled(this.props.order)}
      />
    );
  }
```

And the handleclick method used

```
  handleCheck(checked, key) {
    const { params, updateOrder } = this.props;
    const { sessionId } = params;

    // if doulbeSided option is removed, then clear the inside file.
    if (key === 'doubleSided' && !checked) {
      updateOrder(sessionId, { inside: null });
    }

    // set ink coverage based on printed flag
    if (key === 'printed') {
      const inkCoverage = checked ? 100 : 0;
      updateOrder(sessionId, { inkCoverage });
    }

    // if unprinted, remove doublesided and gloss options
    if (key === 'printed' && !checked) {
      updateOrder(sessionId, { doubleSided: false });
      updateOrder(sessionId, { gloss: false });
    }

    updateOrder(sessionId, { [key]: checked });
  }
```

And the radio button’s method

```
  onClick(id, ordAttribute) {
    const { updateOrder, sessionId, validator } = this.props;
    updateOrder(sessionId, { [ordAttribute]: id });

    if (validator) validator(ordAttribute);
  }
```

I saw that gloss has a service which is toggling disabled or not via the printed key on state here

```
gloss: {
  display: 'Gloss Finish',
  key: 'gloss',
  component: 'checkbox',
  disabled: state => !state.printed,
},
```

I’ve thought about creating a fourth radio button and just deleting the gloss option but I’m not sure where it’s being populated from – also thought about using a display none on the styles of the gloss that is activated via the radio button – but am not sure where to start.

just stated a new job and this is the previous employee's code - trying to figure it out. looks like the state is activated via this Action method:

```
export const updateOrder = (sessionId, payload) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(updateAction({ ...payload }));
  const state = getState();
  const ord = getNewOrderForm(state);
  const minOrdValue = getMinOrdValue(state);
  const { length, width, height, style, blankLength, blankWidth, qty, leadTime, sqFeet } = ord;
  const priceMatrix = style ? getPriceMatrix(state)[style.priceMatrix] : null;

  if (priceMatrix && style && style.calcPrice) {
    dispatch(dispatchNewPrice(ord, style, priceMatrix, minOrdValue));
  }

  if (shouldCalcBlank({width, length, height}, style)) {
    calcBlanks(style, {width, length, height})
    .then(blanks => dispatch(updateAction(blanks)))
    .catch(err => console.log('error', err))
  }

  if (blankLength && blankWidth && qty) {
    calcSquareFeet({ blankLength, blankWidth, qty })
      .then(sqFeet => {
        dispatch(updateAction({ sqFeet }));
        return sqFeet;
      })
      .then(sqFeet => sqFeet > 1000)
      .then(lrgSqFeet => {
        dispatch(updateAction({ lrgSqFeet }));
        return lrgSqFeet;
      })
      .then(lrgSqFeet => {
        if (lrgSqFeet && leadTime === 'rush') {
          dispatch(updateAction({ leadTime: 'standard' }));
        }
      });
  }

  if (sqFeet && (!blankLength || !blankWidth || !qty)) {
    dispatch(updateAction({ sqFeet: 0 }));
  }

  localStorage.setItem(sessionId, JSON.stringify(getNewOrderForm(getState())));
};
```

i thought about adding a the radio button has an id of 'clearwater' so i thought about adding a bool to this method that could then be accessed as clearwater: false (and when onClick is activated, updateOrder then changes it to clearwater: true, and then the gloss object in the service would then check disabled: state => !state.printed && !state.clearwater (this didn't work):

```
export const generateNewOrder = (userid, style, sessionId = uuid()) => dispatch => {
  localStorage.setItem(
    sessionId,
    JSON.stringify({
      userid,
      style,
      sessionId,
      blindShip: true,
      inkCoverage: '100',
      printed: true,
    })
  );
  history.push(`/order/new/${style.styleCode}/${sessionId}`);
  dispatch(
    newOrder({
      userid,
      style,
      sessionId,
      blindShip: true,
      inkCoverage: '100',
      printed: true,
    })
  );

  if (style.type === 'static') {
    const { dims, blankLength, blankWidth } = style;
    const payload = {
      ...dims,
      blankLength,
      blankWidth,
    };

    dispatch(updateOrder(sessionId, payload));
  }
};
```

I was hoping by changing the Service attached to the checkbox, I could add an additional condition that would cause the disabled functionality to be dependent on the state.boardStyle, but this doesn't seem to work (picture below isn't accurate, i changed it to boardStyle):

http://oi65.tinypic.com/wknzls.jpg

This is using redux -- kind of new to redux -- let me know if I'm missing any info -- I will post anything to get this solved.

Any help would be huge – thanks so much!

Comment: the Premium White radio button has an id of "clearwater" which i can access -- and the gloss has a key of gloss which i can access -- do i need to pass this info to the other component via state?

Comment: This line seems suspect to me: `disabled: state => !state.printed` which gets called with `disabled={item.disabled(this.props.order)` .  Does `this.props.order.printed` exist?  I know it says "state" there, but that's not what getting passed in.  You're just using "state" as a param name at this point.

Comment: yeah i'm trying to figure out where that's being pulled from -- is it set on the global state?  i kept trying to look for a state declaration but all i can find is  references. looks like Map is being used to map over items -- I'm not sure how the info is being populated -- (i found a mockData file but it may be populated via firebase?)

Comment: thinking about reviewing my reactJS course but really i wish i could ask another dev (i'm the only dev at this company)

Comment: is there a way to add to that order service code to disable it if another state variable was false as well? (that's the approach i took)

Comment: As an aside, if you aren't already doing so, I suggest adding https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger and/or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/ to your project/browser.  You'll be able to track your data flow more easily this way.

Comment: will do, thanks! i just noticed from the Redux Chrome dev tool that UPDATE_ORDER is the type, so maybe i need to find a way to insert a new key on that state like disabled, set it to false when id === 'clearwater' is selected, then have that bool toggle the disabled or enabled prop . . . ?

Comment: is it weird to answer my own question? oy... well it works! now i just need to find how to create a fourth field for the radio button for version b. thanks stack overflow :) ! u rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i figured it out . . .

there's probably a drier way to do this, but here goes:

first i created a new key [bool] (clearwater, set to false) on generateNewOrder method in Actions:

```
export const generateNewOrder = (userid, style, sessionId = uuid()) => dispatch => {
  localStorage.setItem(
    sessionId,
    JSON.stringify({
      userid,
      style,
      sessionId,
      blindShip: true,
      inkCoverage: '100',
      printed: true,
      clearwater: false,
    })
  );
  history.push(`/order/new/${style.styleCode}/${sessionId}`);
  dispatch(
    newOrder({
      userid,
      style,
      sessionId,
      blindShip: true,
      inkCoverage: '100',
      printed: true,
      clearwater: false
    })
  );

  if (style.type === 'static') {
    const { dims, blankLength, blankWidth } = style;
    const payload = {
      ...dims,
      blankLength,
      blankWidth,
    };

    dispatch(updateOrder(sessionId, payload));
  }
};
```

that gave me access to this state value, which i could then use in the onclick when the radio button was pressed. if the id was clearwater, the bool would be set to true, else it was set to false (only for the other two options because this code is used for other IDs)

```
  onClick(id, ordAttribute) {
    const { updateOrder, sessionId, validator } = this.props;
    updateOrder(sessionId, { [ordAttribute]: id });

    if (validator) validator(ordAttribute);

    if (id === 'clearwater') {
      updateOrder(sessionId, { clearwater: true });
    } else if (id === 'kraft' || id === 'std_white_two_side'){
      updateOrder(sessionId, { clearwater: false });
    }
  }
```

then all i needed to do was add this to the Service. if it was not printed !printed or not clearwater !clearwater, the checkbox would be disabled

```
  const printing = {
    doubleSided: {
      display: 'Two Sided Print',
      key: 'doubleSided',
      component: 'checkbox',
      disabled: state => !state.printed,
    },
    printed: {
      display: 'Printed?',
      key: 'printed',
      component: 'checkbox',
      disabled: () => false,
    },
    gloss: {
      display: 'Gloss Finish',
      key: 'gloss',
      component: 'checkbox',
      disabled: state => !state.printed || !state.clearwater,
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example answering a similar problem, please, have a look. The whole logic is done in redux:
[Want to uncheck the node of the tree structure in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146623/want-to-uncheck-the-node-of-the-tree-structure-in-react-js/56162400#56162400)